# Facebook secure URL for apps

Tags: facebook

Hello I'm very new to the app side of things.

I need to know (as it state from the 1st of OCT) that you need a secure URL for page apps. Does that mean you must have SSL running `https://` or you can just use `http://`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, I believe you have to get a SSL Certificate for your App Page.

From the Facebook Developer Blog - [Keeping Users Safe](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/499/):

> As an app developer, you can help us by:
>
> **Acquiring an SSL Certificate**. Contrary to some feedback we’ve heard,
>   acquiring an SSL certificate is relatively inexpensive, and the
>   ongoing cost of supporting SSL for most apps is low. The sooner your
>   app supports HTTPS the more secure our platform will become. All Apps
>   on Facebook (Canvas and Page Tabs) must support HTTPS by October 1.
>
> **Reviewing the Authentication guide and implement OAuth**. This updated
>   authentication guide walks you through the OAuth 2.0 flow and how to
>   implement OAuth with CSRF protection. Our new OAuth flows provide a
>   more secure and reliable way to obtain access_tokens than our legacy
>   authentication flows. All apps must support the new OAuth flows by
>   September 1.

[Here's their Authentication Guide](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication) (also linked in their blog post).

Comment: Thanks mate I just was not sure - But I was sure You never know with Facebook. Thanks again for your help Shiva ;) Rocketrod

Comment: Sure thing! You are right, you never know with Facebook. Their API won the Worst API of the year award, lot in part due to how frequently they switched up their endpoints, or signatures or parameters. I think developers call it getting "Zucked". https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=2873531